# How do I hide a component on some layouts but still perform work?

Tags: managed-package, visualforce-component

I have a component that we only show on some layouts for an object.  It has a polling function that monitors changes to the object (an object from a managed package). One function of the polling is to refresh the page when some custom field values change.

I need this refresh functionality now on all layouts for this object, but I do not want to display anything on the actual page in the layouts that do not need it.

What I have tried is to put a public boolean on the controller that says whether or not to render the controls. What this does is hide the controls but leaves a large white space on the page where the controls would be. Of course I do not want this space to show.

Here is a simplified version of my page :

```
    <apex:page standardController="zqu__Quote__c" id="customQuoteMetrics" >    
        <c:Z_CustomQuoteMetrics quote="{!zqu__Quote__c.Id}" from="QuoteDetailPage" />
   </apex:page>

    <apex:component controller="CustomQuoteMetrics" allowDML="true" >
    <apex:form id="customQuoteMetrics">
        <apex:actionPoller action="{!queryQuote}"  rerender="metrics"  interval="90" />
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!refreshQuoteNow}">
        <script>
              window.top.location='/{!quoteID}';
        </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:pageBlock id="metrics" rendered="{!showCustomComponent}">
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Any ideas on what I could do differently?
I am a (c#, c++, JavaScript...) developer, but have only been writing apex code on the salesforce platform for about 8 months, so I realize I may not be headed in the right direction.

I asked this on the developer forum but there doesn't seem to be anyone around there. I've always had better experience with stack overflow.

Is there a way to have a component on the page with no content?

Comment: Why did someone down-vote my question without feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

It's hard to say without seeing the wider context of the page code, but I would try wrapping the metrics pageblock in an outputpanel and moving its rendered attribute to that outputpanel.

```
        <apex:component controller="CustomQuoteMetrics" allowDML="true" >
    <apex:form id="customQuoteMetrics">
        <apex:actionPoller action="{!queryQuote}"  rerender="metrics"  interval="90" />
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!refreshQuoteNow}">
        <script>
              window.top.location='/{!quoteID}';
        </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!showCustomComponent}" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlock id="metrics">
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

PS: I assume that the metrics pageBlock contains something in the original code; it seems redundant otherwise.

Comment: Yes of course I removed it as it's irrelevant.

Comment: I added the page code